# Inertia.js shared data security

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I'm developing a personal project using Laravel with Inertia.js. I tried retrieving data from back-end to front-end through HandleInertiaRequests Middleware. I was wondering how will malicious people could get advantage of the data I show up in front-end. Inertia.js webpage discourages retrieving sensible data in this way, but I can't figure out how that will be possible. I apologize if my answer sound a little naive, still pretty new to Laravel ad never used Inertia before. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HandleInertiaRequests Middleware is nothing but a way to merge data into the array that will be available to your JavaScript components (Vue, React, Svelte) on the client side.

It is just a way to avoid repeating yourself on every controller for things that you'll probably need on a lot of pages. For example, instead of getting the data for a Menu component on every controller, you do this only in the HandleInertiaRequests Middleware.

So, they only warn you to be careful with what type of data you put into it. For example, you probably don't want to pass the user password through this in the same way you wouldn't do that using a Blade view instead of Inertia.