# Inertia.js and Laravel - How does the view automatically receive the auth::user() object?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am currently working on a Laravel 8 project and for the first time, I tried using the provided Laravel Breeze scaffolding with Inertia.js and Vue. In the original dashboard scaffolding, the dashboard component can automatically retrieve the `$page.props.auth.user` object, as shown in the image:
[image]

However, if you look at the `<script>` part of the Vue component, the props for these objects aren't there.

My question is, **how does Laravel pass the `auth` object to the `$page` variable?**

I am not sure if my purpose will further help in answering that question, but I'm gonna say it anyway: I have made a polymorphic relationship between two models (a `User` model and a `Student` model) and I wanted the `auth.user` object to also contain information from the associated row in `Student` every request, since I'm gonna use it to display names and other details on a sidebar/navbar.
[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$page.props.auth.user` comes from the `share` method at `\app\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests.php` middleware.

I've explained a little bit about this middleware on [another answer you can read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485101/inertia-js-shared-data-security/68672671#68672671).

You won't see the prop on the page component because it's a shared property. Give a closer look at [the docs on this](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#accessing-shared-data).

Comment: Hello! Perhaps I can also load the `userable` information needed to be consistently displayed in the main layout. I'll try this out later and will mark as correct shortly after.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
app\Http\Middleware\HandleInertiaRequests.php
```

in
`share` function